# Low rpm when gas is pumped

Tags: honda, prelude

I have a 2001 Honda Prelude. Every time I pump gas the rpm dies down and even turns off some times. It doesn't matter if it's $10, $20, or a full tank it happens. I just wanna know what was can do to fix this....

Comment: So your engine is running _while_ you are pumping gas?

Comment: Here is what you can do to fix the issue. Turn of your engine while pumping gas!

Comment: My engine is turned off while I'm pumping gas. It's every time I start the car after I'm done pumping gas

Comment: If you remove the fuel cap and replace it, does the same thing happen (without putting gas into the vehicle)?

Comment: I tried that an it don't do it only when I pump gas.

Comment: "My engine is turned off while I'm pumping gas. It's every time I start the car after I'm done pumping gas" you should add that to the question lol

Answer (score 5):

This type of symptom is normally a result of an EVAP purge solenoid that is stuck open.

Most if not all Honda vehicles are equipped with on board vapor recovery. This system collects the fumes that are inside the gas tank while filling the tank. The fumes are passed into the EVAP charcoal canister to store them. When the car is running the EVAP purge solenoid pulls air through the canister and into the engine to be burned.

If the purge solenoid is stuck open it can allow the fumes from the tank to enter the engine while the engine is off. The fumes will flood the engine.