# How Does a Stuck Purge Solenoid Cause Problems

Tags: rough-idle, acceleration, purge-solenoid

In the WSM for my car, it lists "purge solenoid valve malfunction" as a cause of both a low idle with excessive shaking and loss of power during acceleration.

I'm wondering the exact mechanism / why / how these problems can be caused by a purge solenoid valve malfunction, and if the problem would be reflected in fuel trim numbers.

Comment: Is this related to the crankcase ventilation system?

Comment: @Zaid No, it's part of the evap system.

Comment: [This](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22066/675) answer is a start...

Answer (score 1):

The air taken into the engine from the charcoal canister via the purge valve will be saturated with fuel vapors.  The engine ECU will not be expecting this, so the engine will run rich.  You would expect the fuel trim to be out.